# To show difference between two bars in high charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, highcharts

I want to show difference values in a new line between the two bar charts in high chart plugins, I've create simple bar chart in high charts, but I need to show difference between two bars in the new line.
I'm explaining this in below image, please refer following image.

[image: High Chart]

please help me to fix this , 
Image 2,
 i want to show that information in below format/design, is it possible in high charts?
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6oyd.png)

Comment: Could you paste the js code?

Comment: Highcharts.chart('container', {
    data: {
        table: 'datatable'
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Units'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
});

Comment: Actually basic barcharts i need, im getting example from following link, please refer it,
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/

Comment: Please update your question with the code. Not as a comment.

Comment: i'm did not create any code Kelvin, please tell me  is possible or not. to draw like that line and show difference value.

Comment: It is possible. One moment pleast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got as far as extracting the data from the table to calculate the differences. However, as the example has some negative differences e.g. -1, it will depend what graph you would like to put this information on as it would need to have a negative y axis.

The following jQuery code will exact all values, find the difference between the first and second and then add this to an array called diffChart.

```
var graphs = $('#datatable tbody tr');

var diffChart = [];

for (var i = 0, len = graphs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var target = $('#datatable tbody tr').eq(i);
    var bar1 = target.find('td').eq(0).text();
  var bar2 = target.find('td').eq(1).text();

  var diff = Number(bar1) - Number(bar2);

  diffChart.push(diff);

}
```

You can view an example of the console log output in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33q7zdth/1/)

Sorry I couldn't be of much help past this.

Comment: I would suggest using the absolute value of the difference, though I am still unclear what the desired plot result is, regardless.

Comment: i need one more help Kelvin,

Comment: @SivakumarMunusamy How far did you get?

Comment: Please see question again and refer "Image 2"